# prove that $n$-manifold has a countable basic

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

$M$ is a $n$-topological manifold if it is a a topology space and each point of $M$ has a neighborhood that is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

How do I prove that $n$-topological manifold has a countable basic

Thank you any help

Comment: Edited the best I could. Please edit the countable basic sentence for it to make sense. Please add your comments as to how to approach the problem or how you tried to do this and we will be glad to guide you.

Comment: The claim is false. Not so hard to construct a counterexample.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that this definition doesn't require $M$ be Hausdorff, so, for instance, permits pathologies like the line with two origins (or a line with uncountably many origins, for that matter).

Comment: $M$ is first-countable (a countable basis of neighborhoods at each point $m \in M$), but not necessarily second-countable (a countable basis for the entire topology).

Answer (score 4):

With this formulation, you can't. $M$ might be the disjoint union of uncountably many copies of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: i proof that n - manifold is hausdorrff,anh it is locally compact but i can't proof n-manifold with that definition will has a countable basic

Comment: @user270995 Nobody can, because as Hagen said, it's not true. It's not even true if  you demand that the manifold is connected.

Comment: oh sorry thank you i just want to do something new thank you for your advice

Comment: so i need to delete this question

Comment: how can i delete it? please